Show that $ \left( \int_1^\infty f \right)^2 \leq \int_1^\infty x^2(f(x))^2 dx $
In Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right (4e), Chapter 6A (Inner Product Spaces), exercise 18 is as follows:

(a) Suppose $f:  [1, \infty) \to [0, \infty)$ is continuous. Show that
$$
\left( \int_1^\infty f \right)^2 \leq \int_1^\infty x^2(f(x))^2 dx
$$
(b) For which continuous functions $f: [1, \infty) \to [0, \infty)$ is the inequality in (a) an equality with both sides finite?

I'm having trouble with (a). Here is what I have tried:
I think that $\langle f, g \rangle = \int_1^\infty f(x)g(x) dx$ is an inner product. Also, $ f(x) \leq xf(x)$, so $ \left( \int_1^\infty f(x) dx\right)^2 \leq \left( \int_1^\infty xf(x) dx \right)^2 = \langle x, f \rangle ^4. $ By Cauchy-Schwartz,
\begin{align}
|\langle xf \rangle| \leq \lVert x \rVert \lVert f \rVert 
&= \left( \int_1^\infty x dx \right)^2 \left( \int_1^\infty f(x) dx \right)^2.  
\end{align}
Hence, $ \left( \int_1^\infty f(x) dx \right)^2 \leq \left( \left( \int_1^\infty x dx \right)^2 \left( \int_1^\infty f(x) dx\right)^2 \right)^4. $ Not sure if that helps me though, especially since $\int_1^\infty xdx$ diverges.
I think that the fact that $ \sqrt{f(x)} \leq f(x) \leq xf(x) $ implies that $ \int_1^\infty f(x) dx \leq \int_1^\infty f^2(x) dx \leq \int_1^\infty (xf(x))^2 dx$. If I could somehow show that $(\int_1^\infty f(x) dx)^2  \leq \int_1^\infty f^2(x) dx$, I think that would work.
Another way I was thinking about the problem: if the RHS $ \int_1^\infty x^2(f(x))^2 dx $ diverges, then the inequality is always true. So we can focus on when the RHS converges, but I'm not sure when that is.
FWIW, this chapter introduced inner products, norms, the orthogonal complement, pythagorean theorem, Cauchy-Schwartz inequality, triangle inequality, and parallelogram equality.

Edit: as mention in the comments by Theo Bendit an application of Cauchy-Schwartz-Bunyakowski’s  to the inner product $$\langle xf(x),x^{-1}\rangle=\int_{[1,\infty)}xf(x)\frac1x\,dx$$ yields the desired result. This exactly as it is done in older postings in MSE.
Here, I provide a semi-probabilistic argument.  Notice that $f(x)=x^2f(x)\frac1{x^2}$. As $\int^\infty_1 x^{-2}\,dx=1$, an application of Jensen’s inequality yields the desired inequality:
$$\Big(\int_{[1,\infty)}x^2 f(x)\frac{dx}{x^2}\Big)^2\leq\int_{[1,\infty)} x^4 f^2(x)\frac{dx}{x^2}$$
